# Join MySQL tables, select rows with column starting with string and use multiplication to filter

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-like

I've got two databases, I'm joining them like this:

```
select *
from business,activity 
where business.primary_activity_id = activity.id;
```

However, I would like to select from this joined query the rows where identifier (which was imported from the activity table) starts with "01."

I was trying this query:

```
select * 
from business,activity
where business.primary_activity_id = activity.id
    and identifier like "01.";
```

Well, it didn't work. Empty query.

Checked manually the table and there are rows where identifier start with "01." 
Can someone enlight my journey?

Comment: Pls try to add %. Identifier  like '01.%'

Comment: Thanks @anonyXmous, it worked

Comment: Glad to help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @anonyXmous answered as a comment, I want to add a few more things.

First, the wildcard character for `LIKE` is `%` to match a substring of any length, including zero length.  The wildcard for a single character is underscore (`'_'`).

Second, you should not be using commas in the `from` clause.  Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Third, table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.  And then use them to qualify all column names.

Fourth, use single quotes for string constants.  So:

```
select b.*, a.*
from business b join
     activity a
     on b.primary_activity_id = a.id
where a.identifier like '01.%';
```